# Cloud SQL Wordpress DB connection always on

Tags: sql, sql-server, wordpress, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have just managed to do this basic installation including the Batcache and the Gapp engine plugin for wordpress on Google cloud using Cloud SQL.
I just saw that the total usage is 42 hours of the Cloud SQL instance.

My site has no posts and is fairly new.
There are no followers neither visitors.
I am wondering why the SQL is always on ?
I have it to activate only when requested rather than always on.

Thoughts ?

Comment: What pricing plan are you using, _per package_ or _per use_?

Comment: Per use only. 0.0025 per hour

Comment: Do you have a local environment to test it on? The problem could be with your config/plugins

Comment: Yes I do. I only have 2 plugins. Google App Engine for WordPress and Batchache manager.

Comment: What does the "active connections" graph on Developers Console show? Can you try to log into your Cloud SQL instance and do a "show full processlist" to find out what's connecting to your database?

Comment: Hi @TonyTseng Active Connections graph shows 1 connection active 24/7. I am unable to locate Cloud SQL instance "Show Full processlist" option. can you advise where this is ?

Comment: +----+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------------
----+
| Id | User | Host          | db   | Command | Time | State | Info
    |
+----+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------------
----+
| 12 | root | 27.32.---.--- | NULL | Query   |    0 | NULL  | show full processl
ist |
+----+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------------
----+
1 row in set (0.33 sec)

Comment: Something doesn't quite add up. Can you try to connect to the instance a few times throughout the day and see if you see something else? Also another option is to turn on the query log and restart your instance.

Answer (score 1):

If you set it to on demand it will only connect when its needed. After a few minutes it will shut down again. There will be a spool up time for the first person but it should be very short.