# Connection Active Google Cloud SQL

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have setup wordpress on Google Cloud SQL and Google Cloud.
I have only 2 minimal plugins setup Gapps engine and Batchache manager
There are no posts, no other plugins.
I have no visitors or followers.

My issue is I still have an active connection with Google Coud SQL which is charged at 0.025 per hour.

I have 1 connection which always stays on.
This connection I would like to close when not in use.

These are my full process list

```
+----+------+---------------+------+---------+------+
| Id |    User | Host | db | Command | Time | State | Info |1 
| 12 | root | 27.32.---.--- | NULL | Query | 0 | NULL | show full processl ist 
| +----+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+------------------- ----+ 1 row in set (0.33 sec) –
```

Comment: Google Developers' Console -> Cloud SQL -> your instance -> Edit  Activation Policy -> "On Demand" The instance will be turned on to handle incoming connections and shut down after a few minutes of inactivity.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25798277/cloud-sql-wordpress-db-connection-always-on .

Answer (score 1):

WordPress on App Engine is optimized for high traffic sites, so batcache keeps Cloud SQL alive.

You can tune that. See https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-app-engine/other_notes/ or search for "optimize wordpress batcache on app engine".